# How to fix android error: incompatible types: SliderAdapter cannot be converted to Adapter

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-adapter

I am trying to make an on-board activity in android studio.
But I am facing a problem.
This is my adapter code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;

public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public SliderAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    int images[] = {
        R.drawable.interview,
        R.drawable.send,
        R.drawable.click,
        R.drawable.call
    };

    int headings [] = {
        R.string.first_title,
        R.string.second_title,
        R.string.third_title,
        R.string.fourth_title
    };

    int descriptions[] = {
        R.string.first_decs,
        R.string.second_decs,
        R.string.third_decs,
        R.string.fourth_decs
    };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return headings.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == (ConstraintLayout)object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slides_layout,container,false);

        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.slider_image);
        TextView heading = view.findViewById(R.id.slider_heading);
        TextView desc = view.findViewById(R.id.slider_decs);

        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        heading.setText(headings[position]);
        desc.setText(descriptions[position]);

        container.addView(view);

        return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((ConstraintLayout)object);
    }
}
```

**This is my main activity code**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class OnBoardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    LinearLayout dots;

    SliderAdapter sliderAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_on_board);
        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.slider);
        dots = findViewById(R.id.dots);
        sliderAdapter = new SliderAdapter(this);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(sliderAdapter);
    }
}
```

But then I am facing this error

[image]

please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extends **ReyclerView** instead of PagerAdapter in **SliderAdapter** class.

check the [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/viewpager2-in-android-with-example/)